# Removing a color override from a paragraph style in Adobe Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, formatting

I accidentally specified a color to a paragraph style, which is based on some other. How do I clear this color override, so that I can use the color of the base paragraph?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pick the color of your parent paragraph style.
See in the General tab of the para style option, no text color is specified anymore.
You're back to the inherited text color swatch:

[image]

Comment: I see. It seems that the only way to reset one property is to match it to the ones of its parent. I don't know why there is no simple interface to remove the override of an individual property, even though there are for some others such as text box. Anyway, I really appreciate your nice animation to help me out!

Comment: Well, the thing is a paragraph style must have a text color assigned. FYI, a character style can have it ignored, so you can Ctrl+click on the assigned swatch to    remove it.

Answer (score 0):

- Place the cursor inside the actual paragraph.
- In the Paragraph Styles panel, right click the paragraph name and choose 'Apply & Clear Overrides'.

[image]

Comment: Just a word of caution... *never* use the "Basic" style.. leave it as it is. If you alter text and want to save it as a style, create a *new style*. *Don't* merely redefine "Basic". It'll save you mountains of headaches in the future. --- I know this answer isn't advocating the use of "Basic", still it's worth a mention `:)`

Comment: Correct, this was just a quick screenshot of a default blank document.